# Solution to $ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{1+e^{\tau(x-\mu)}}dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Does anyone know the answer to this integral

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{1+e^{\tau(x-\mu)}}dx
$$

which vaguely resembles Fermi-Dirac integrals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a geometric series, rewrite the integral as$$\begin{align}e^{\tau\mu}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-(\alpha+\tau)x}}{1+e^{-\tau(x-\mu)}}dx&=e^{\tau\mu}\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n\int_0^\infty e^{-(\alpha+\tau)x-n\tau(x-\mu)}dx\\&=e^{\tau\mu}\sum_{n\ge0}(-e^{\tau\mu})^n\int_0^\infty e^{-(\alpha+(n+1)\tau)x}dx\\&=e^{\tau\mu}\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-e^{\tau\mu})^n}{\alpha+\tau+n\tau}\\&=\frac{e^{\tau\mu}}{\tau}\Phi(-e^{\tau\mu},\,1,\,\alpha/\tau+1)\end{align}$$in terms of the [Lerch transcendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Definition)$$\Phi(z,\,s,\,\alpha):=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{z^n}{(n+\alpha)^s}.$$

Answer (score 2):

If you enjoy hypergeometric functions
$$\int\frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{1+e^{\tau(x-\mu)}}dx=-\frac{e^{-\alpha x  }}{\alpha }\, _2F_1\left(1,-\frac{\alpha }{\tau };1-\frac{\alpha }{\tau };-e^{\tau  (x-\mu)}\right)$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{1+e^{\tau(x-\mu)}}dx=\frac{e^{\mu  \tau }}{\alpha +\tau }\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{\alpha +\tau }{\tau };\frac{\alpha+2\tau  }{\tau };-e^{\mu  \tau}\right)$$ if $\Re(\alpha +\tau )>0\land \Re(\tau )>0$